# user access to /var/lib/tor denied after fresh tor install on raspberry pi 4

Tags: configuration, tor-install

Raspberry PI 4 running Raspbian Full Install, I followed the instructions at
https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/setup/install/
following the debian/ubuntu section but using the default repository as the docs for using the suggested repo said no support for arm 32
which means I just ran

```
sudo apt install tor
```

it created configuration docs under /etc/tor and
it created the folder /var/lib/tor appar which seemed to be owned by debian-tor
going back to the "Setup onion services" directions at
https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/setup/
I installed nginx and verified a domain name would connect to it on port 80 from outside my network.
I got to Step 2: Configure your Tor onion service and it is talking about copying keys and info to the folder /var/lib/tor, which I don't have access to.
Per question [21492](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/21492/tor-var-lib-tor-permissions) I ran

```
ps -o user= -p $(pgrep -x tor)
```

to verify tor was running under debian-tor, which it was. The one answer (not accepted) suggested

```
sudo chown -R debian-tor:debian-tor /var/lib/tor
```

which didn't make sense to me but I tried it. I still couldn't access the directory. Then bringing my own very limited knowledge to bear I ran

```
sudo chown -R pi:pi /var/lib/tor
```

and now I have full access to that directory and can presumably complete the installation process.
Unlike another question, [15185](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/15185/directory-cannot-be-readed-permission-denied-after-update-to-0-3-0), I did not have issues starting tor, I just couldn't put my keys where they needed to go.

```
sudo systemctl restart tor
```

I configured torrc with

```
 HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/test/
 HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

I created /var/lib/tor/test and copied the three files created by mkp224o (hostname, hs_ed25519_public_key, hs_ed25519_secret_key) to that folder and re-started tor. The onion address failed to load in a working tor browser on my phone. Re-assigned the /var/lib/tor back to debian-tor, restarted tor, same results. Not seeing any errors on screen, the folders /var/log/tor and /var/log/runit/tor are empty. The /var/lib/tor/state document has some info about circuits built and tor addresses sampled, no errors.
That's about all the info I have. My questions are

1. did I create some terrible security risk or other issue by taking ownership of /var/lib/tor? I assume so otherwise it would not have been inaccessible in the first place.
2. do the instructions at torproject need to be updated?
3. where are my error logs or other clues I could follow concerning my test domain not being on the tor network?

Comment: I have my first onion page up and running. I had to chown to pi the public and private keys, I had to enable logs in the torrc (I had thought those would be automatic) and I had to chown to pi the log folder and files so they could be written to. I know this isn't "right" but it gave me logs and allowed tor to read the keys. I also found I had to issue the command "tor" on a command line to start tor. Now that I know that I see options to enable this as a daemon, but it wasn't automatic or obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, run `systemctl status` as root and see the Tor service name, after that you will see the *actual* running log with `journalctl -feu your-service-name`